# How to check if a number has a whatsapp account?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, whatsapp

We have configured the WhatsApp cloud API (not as a BSP). We use a messages endpoint to send messages to our customers. But we need to validate if the customer number has a WhatsApp account associated with it.

Is there any endpoint available to check if a number has a WhatsApp account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an option in On-premises API using [contacts API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/on-premises/reference/contacts) but there is no option for Cloud API.

Hope they will provide in the future.